# Add windows user for smb shares

Tags: samba, home-server

I am migrating all my files to my homeserver. I don't want to have a Domain controller, because I am currently not willing to configurate all this.

I have a local computer YODA and a user on this computer YODA\thefalcon. Is there a way to add this user from my local computer to the server, so the local user can login to the server without having to log in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. Your server won't understand the credentials from your local PC because the SIDs would be completely different even if you have the same name on both servers.

If you're looking to have a central file space, you can just map the share as a network drive and the auto-login capabilities will take care of your requirement.

Comment: Thanks, can u tell me if there is a simple way to migrate a Windows user to a Linux PDC, including all settings, directories etc, so there is no difference to before?

Comment: @th3falc0n You'd need to ask a new question since that's not in scope of this question.